# How do I highlight the underlines of two edittext fields simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

I have two edittext fields. What I want is, when the user types something in second text field, the underlines of both the fields should highlight with the same color. [image]

In the above picture,  there are two edittext fields,  one for country code and one for mobile no. As you can see, only one field is highlighted,  I want both of them highlighted and cursor should remain in the mobile no. field.

Comment: you need to use **TextInputLayout**

Comment: How can I use TextInputLayout? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @OjasvaJain Can you show your `XML` code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `view`, contains `EditText` and an underline. `EditText` has no background, and you can use an `ImageView` (or a view with right color) as the underline.